# Re-initialising a view after the save button has been touched

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, xcode4

I have a TabBar Application with 2 tabs saving/fetching data to and from CoreData. The problem that I am having is that when the form has been filled and the user has touched the save button the view is not re-loaded or re-initialised. All I want is for the view to be ready for the user to repeat the process with the next set of information. I am probably not thinking about this in the correct way so a pointer in the right direction would be very much appreciated...

Do I need to manually set everything including the managedObjectContext etc. to nil? Or is there something that I can do with methods like viewWillDisappear that will elegantly help me to "re-initialise" that specific tab?

I ave read up the Apple docs on view hierarchies, and life cycles but I just seem to have confused myself...

Thanks in advance for any suggestions, referrals to code or even recommendations on relevant reading material.

Comment: thats very unspecific. show us your code, or what you've tried. After pressing the submit button a method will be called, right? what are you doing in there? you should start a new database fetch there and reset your textfields.

Comment: Thanks for your time and response - I now realise I'm showing my ignorance but I'm not sure that including my code would help. At the moment I'm clearing down all arrays, UITextFields and labels manually after the save sends the information to core data - but it just feels clumsy so I assume I'm missing something. All I want is for my form on the tab to return to its initial state after the save button is touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is reload any data to their default states when the user taps a button. Unfortunately, you'll have to do this manually, setting each IBOutlet's value to a meaningful default (probably the empty string).

There are two ways I can think of that would help make this more elegant:

- Use an IBOutletCollection and fast enumeration to loop over all the IBOutlets and not have a bunch of code to do each one individually.
- If you're switching tabs in between these events, you can something neat and use your app delegate as your `UITabBarControllerDelegate` for the `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` to call the clearing-out method for you instead of relying on `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Thanks Ash, I think I like the sound of the 2nd option - will spend some time on working it into my app...